# no feed_previous argument for tensorflow basic_rnn_seq2seq function

Tags: tensorflow

The `embedding_rnn_seq2seq` function in tensorflows seq2seq module provides a `feed_previous` argument, which means that during decoding it only uses the first decoder input, and then for subsequent decoder inputs it uses the previous decoder output. Is there a simple way to get this behavior from the `basic_rnn_seq2seq` function?

Answer (score 0):

This API is now deprecated, but if anyone's still looking for a solution I suggest looking at this GitHub repo: [raindeer/seq2seq_experiments](https://github.com/raindeer/seq2seq_experiments/blob/master/model.py#L81)

In short, to create their decoder, the author uses the following (the important part being `loop_function`):

```
def _init_seq2seq(self, encoder_inputs, decoder_inputs, cell, feed_previous):

    def inference_loop_function(prev, _):
        prev = tf.nn.xw_plus_b(prev, self.w_softmax, self.b_softmax)
        return tf.to_float(tf.equal(prev, tf.reduce_max(prev, reduction_indices=[1], keep_dims=True)))

    loop_function = inference_loop_function if feed_previous else None

    with variable_scope.variable_scope('seq2seq'):
        _, final_enc_state = rnn.rnn(cell, encoder_inputs, dtype=dtypes.float32)
        return seq2seq.rnn_decoder(decoder_inputs, final_enc_state, cell, loop_function=loop_function)
```